# How to find an object with a specific property which is in the array of an array, by using NSPredicate?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

Suppose I have the following objects

```
class A { 

NSArray *arrayOfB;
}

class B {

NSString *name;

}
```

Now, I have an array  of As like below and each A contains 10 objects of B within its property arrayOfB.

```
NSArray *arrayOfAs; //contains objects of A
```

How can I get the objects of A depending upon specific match of name property of Bs inside of A, by using NSPredicate ?

I've tried googling, etc. and even writing various style of NSPredicate but did not succeed. Can anyone enlighten me how to do it?

This is what I tried so far:

```
NSPredicate *p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(SELF.name BEGINSWITH[c] %@ IN SELF.arrayOfB)",myText];

NSArray *mySearchedArrayOfAs = [arrayOfAs filteredArrayUsingPredicate:p];
```

But I run into error which says "Unable to parse the predicate".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to use `ANY` operator, like this:

```
NSPredicate *p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY arrayOfB.name BEGINSWITH[c] %@", myText];
```

Comment: I do not have a setup to check this at the moment. Let me know if this does not work, and I'll delete the answer.